# Expand treeview nodes

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm displaying a small model (a survey) in a treeview. The nodes (= answers) have checkboxes and when loading a survey, marked answers (with the property "IsSelected" = true) are successfully checked.

What I am having troubles with is to **expand those nodes where "IsSelected" = true on the initial load.** I have tried to use a style to accomplish this, but could not get it working. See, e.g., the following style:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
            Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected}">
    </Setter>
</Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This looks good (at least to me), but it has no effect - I guess there is a problem with the datacontext and the Binding cannot grasp the right "IsSelected" - that should be the one that I'm also binding the checkboxes to. **How can I get the right datacontext and have these nodes expanded?** Thank you very much for your help or hints!

---

For completeness, here is the full xamlfor the treeview:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionTree}">

<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Question}" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource QuestionConverter}}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Group}" ItemsSource="{Binding Options}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GroupOption}" ItemsSource="{Binding Options}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainOption}" ItemsSource="{Binding MainOptions}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>

<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
                Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected}">
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And also my small model:

```
public class Question
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MainOption> MainOptions { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class MainOption
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MetaItemId { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<GroupOption> Options { get; set; }
}

public class GroupOption
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MetaItemId { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you aren't using INotifyPropertyChanged anywhere... Without that WPF doesn't know that a property has changed

Comment: Well, there is no change at all. I'm talking about the initial display. When loaded, I want the treeview to have all items that are 'checked' expanded. It works for the "checked"-property..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working.. silly me.. I had set the "IsExpanded" for the LEAVES instead of the NODES.. Adding a property "ContainsSelectedItems" to both NODE-classes Question and Group

```
    public bool ContainsSelectedItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.MainOptions != null && this.MainOptions.Any(x => x.IsSelected == true))
            {
                return true;
            };
            if (this.Groups != null && this.Groups.SelectMany(x => x.Options).Any(y => y.IsSelected == true))
            {
                return true;
            };
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and using this property in the xaml

```
       <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding ContainsSelectedItems}" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

works!

Answer (score 0):

If you have already data bound the `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` property to your data property, then you can just set the `TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` property from the `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` property. Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}">
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Although this will of course tie the two properties together, which you may not want.

Comment: This has no effect, I wish I could tell you why but I cannot :o(

Comment: Sheridan, thanks for your comment, I guess you misunderstood me because I chose a bad parameter name: I have NOT data bound the TreeViewItem.IsSelected-Property. All I have done so far is bound the checkboxes' IsChecked-Property to a custom property that is named "IsSelected".